# Proving that $\sin(a)\cos(b)$ and $\cos(a)\sin(b)$ identities are identical using $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This [website](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html) states the two trig identities below are identical:

[\begin{array}{l}
\sin (a)\cos(b) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\sin (a + b) + \sin (a - b)} \right] \Rightarrow 1\\
\cos (a)\sin (b) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\sin (a + b) - \sin (a - b)} \right] \Rightarrow 2
\end{array}]
and you can prove this through the use of  the identity:

$\sin (-x) =  -\sin (x)$

Could help me see how to show this? Thanks.

Comment: That's not what the site says. There is a minus in the second (the fourth on the site). With that in mind, you just have to exchange $a$ and $b$.

Comment: there's a typo in your second identity: the second sine should be subtracted

Comment: Thanks sorry, didnt notice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a type error in the $2$nd case.

$$\text{ It's    }   2\cos A\sin B=\sin(A+B)-\sin(A-B)$$

$$\text{ If }2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$$

Put $A=-A,$   $$\text{So, }2\sin (-A)\cos B=\sin(-A+B)+\sin(-A-B)$$

$$\text{Or }-2\sin A\cos B=\sin(B-A)-\sin(A+B)$$

$$\implies 2\sin A\cos B=\sin(B+A)-\sin(B-A)$$

Exchange $A,B$

Answer (score 2):

switch $a$ and $b$ in the second identity:
$$
\cos (b)\sin (a) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\sin (b + a) + \sin (b - a)} \right]
\\ = \frac{1}{2}\left[ {\sin (a + b) - \sin (a - b)} \right]
$$